# How to change UI-settings per folder in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, themes

I use firebase, and i want to distinguish 3 types of folders:
- the server side code (SRC + BUILD)
- the client side code

because, the errors at runtime are indicated for the BUILD folder, and i change this file, and it is useless because I need to change it from the src folder. So I want VS to put a RED background color when I open a file from the BUILD dir. So I do not modify this auto-generated file inadvertently.

Any plugin for that ? Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension and add a Tab coloring rule with **Document paths regex** set to \\BUILD\\:

[image]

[image]